# Highlight / Focus Color QCheckbox, QRadiobutton, QPushbutton

Tags: c++, qt, styles, qpushbutton, qcheckbox

at the moment I am "playing" with C++ QT and Stylesheets. Normally I found everything in the documenttion, but unfortunatly the following problem not:

[ExamplePic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3qTi.png)

In the example Picture you'll see my edited QPushButtons, QChecksBoxes and QRadioButtons. If they have the "focus", they get a "blue rectangle".
And this is my Question: How can I edit this rectangle? Because I want to have it red. (or even not present)
I tried with "*:focus" but this is not working.
Also "QPalette::Highlight" is not the right thing.

Thanks in Advance
BR
THW

Comment: Can you show us a stylesheet code?

Comment: Try with `border : none` or check the element `PE_FrameFocusRect` in QStyle.h

Comment: Of course, here is the code of the QPushbutton: `QPushButton:enabled, QToolButton:enabled {
              border: 1px solid #8f8f91;
              border-radius: 6px;
              background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                                stop: 0 #000000, stop: 1 #111111);
          }`

Comment: `QPushButton:focus{
              border : none;
          }` is not working.  How can I use `PE_FrameFocusRect`. So you have an example?

Comment: If you want to use `PE_FrameFocusRect` : see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylepainter.html#drawPrimitive)

Comment: @`PE_FrameFocusRect` - If I understand correctly, this is not like a Stylesheet (CSS) in QT, isn't it? Normally I have to override the paintEvent() function to use "DrawPrimitive", or is there any "global" and easy solution like the Stylesheet?

Comment: Well if it's a system selection (it's seems to be) by key focus you want to not present use `outline: 0`. If change color - `outline-color: <color>`. From CSS syntax: `outline: outline-color || outline-style || outline-width | inherit`

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you showed us your current Stylesheet code for the UI in the screen shot. When you say focus do you mean edit focus or when the mouse is over it?  For QPushButton you might want to try customising :hover and :default

Comment: Yes, `outline` is what I am searching for..... now I have to play. Thanks!